# Infinite scroll component using GraphQL and IntersectionObserver

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, intersection-observer

I have few experience with React and I am trying to do Infinite scroll using GraphQL and IntersectionObserver, all work but I am getting the twice the results I request for. I guess it's from a double render, one from @apollo/client `fetchMore` and other from the IntersectionObserver hook but I don't quite understand it and I don't know how to fix it.

The IntersectionObserver hook:

```js
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function useIntersection(options?: IntersectionObserverInit): IntersectionHook {
    const [entry, setEntry] = useState<IntersectionObserverEntry>();
    const observer = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();
    const target = useRef<Element | null>(null);

    const setSentinel = useCallback<IntersectionHook[0]>(
        (sentinel) => {
            if (!observer.current) {
                observer.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => setEntry(entries[0]), options);
            }

            if (target.current) {
                observer.current.unobserve(target.current);
            }

            target.current = sentinel;

            if (target.current) {
                observer.current.observe(target.current);
            }
        },
        [options],
    );

    return [setSentinel, entry];
}

type IntersectionHook = [(sentinel: Element | null) => void, IntersectionObserverEntry | undefined];
```

The component using the hook:

```js
import { Fragment, ReactElement, ReactNode, useEffect } from "react";
import useIntersection from "../hooks/intersectionHook";

export default function InfiniteComponent(props: InfiniteComponentProps): ReactElement {
    const [setSentinel, entry] = useIntersection();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (entry?.isIntersecting) {
            props.onNext();
        }
    }, [props, entry]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {props.children}
            {props.next && <div ref={setSentinel}></div>}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export interface InfiniteComponentProps {
    next?: boolean;
    onNext: () => Promise<unknown>;
    children: ReactNode;
}
```

The page using the component:

```js
export default function IndexArtist(): ReactElement | null {
    const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery<IndexArtistData, IndexArtistVars>(INDEX_ARTIST, {
        variables: { limit: 3 },
    });

    if (loading) {
        return null;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <Redirect to="/error" />;
    }

    if (!data?.artists.nodes.length) {
        return <Redirect to="/error" />;
    }

    return (
        <BoxElement $variant="page">
            <InfiniteComponent
                next={data.artists.page.next}
                onNext={async () => fetchMore({ variables: { cursor: data.artists.page.cursor } })}
            >
                {/* The code to render */}
            </InfiniteComponent>
        </BoxElement>
```

With the above code, I request 3 results and I get 3 results when loading the page but when I scroll down until the `sentinel` of the IntersectionObserver hook to fetch more results I get 6 results (first I get 3 results but shortly after, a few miliseconds after, I get othe 3 results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still open to suggestions. The next solution does not seems the more elegant, but it is the only I found.

The component using the hook:

```js
import { Fragment, ReactElement, ReactNode, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import useIntersection from "../hooks/intersectionHook";

export default function InfiniteComponent(props: InfiniteComponentProps): ReactElement {
    const [wait, setWait] = useState(false);
    const ready = useRef(!wait);
    const [entry, setSentinel] = useIntersection();

    useEffect(() => {
        ready.current = !wait;
    }, [wait]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMore = async (): Promise<void> => {
            setWait(true);
            await props.onMore();
            setWait(false);
        };

        if (ready.current && entry?.isIntersecting) {
            fetchMore();
        }
    }, [entry, props]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {props.children}
            {props.next && !wait && <div ref={setSentinel}></div>}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export interface InfiniteComponentProps {
    next?: boolean;
    onMore: () => Promise<unknown>;
    children: ReactNode;
}
```